# Windows 7 is blocking on website I can't even load it

Tags: windows-7, website, blocking

I desactivated the antivirus, firewall, went to internet options privacy added to the allow list for SITES and nothing happened.

Windows defender its already OFF. Checked using HIDEMYASS and could access to the website so it means that its not the browser. I already tried with IE (bad words) but same result = nothing.

I checked the host file but it doesn't seem to have some IP added :S

What else can I try?

Comment: At home or at work?  There may be a policy on the router, domain, external firewall, etc. preventing this.

Comment: What website?  Seems to be a domain and or network issue rather then Operating system.

Comment: Checked already disabling firewall, not using router, im at home

Comment: I was able to surf that website with the same IP that I'm using now...

Comment: Clear your cache and try an alternative dns server.

Answer (score 0):

I need to know what error message it is giving you when you try to access the site. Have you tried running the windows network troubleshooter? All you have to do is right-click on the bottom right of the screen where it shows your internet status and then select troubleshoot problems. This can resolve a lot of issues, at least give you an idea of whats going, or an error code you can post here and Google.

However, a lot of times this can be the result of the clock on your computer being off. Such as being set to a date in the past/future. When this happens it looks to you computer that the security certificate that the website is offering is invalid.

Comment: I got my clock with bad time, but now I sync I will reboot and see if it works properly now... if works I will Kxll you!

Comment: Nothing changed same... and the clock its set with internet with the right time...

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to steamgifts.com
Try reloading: steamgifts.­com
Additional suggestions:
Access a cached copy of steamgifts.­com
Search on Google:

Checked the website and its UP

Comment: you may have to go into the bios of your computer and change the time there

Comment: Aren't those times Sync with bios and windows?

Comment: They are supposed to be, but sometimes errors with the OS can prevent the settings you enter from inside the OS to be transferred to the CMOS settings. Basically just a case of if it doesn't work one way do the same thing a different way.

Comment: Do you know what DNS server you are using to resolve addresses?

Comment: I used google DNS and nothing happened... now its working but also now its plugged to the router and I dunno if its cuz of that or what is it that make it work...

Comment: @WindowsMidRangeUser Have you tried running the windows network troubleshooter? All you have to do is right-click on the bottom right of the screen where it shows your internet status and then select troubleshoot problems. This can resolve a lot of issues, at least give you an idea of whats going, or an error code you can post here and Google.